# cannot move out of borrowed content - ref doesn't work

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
enum MyEnum1 {
  val1, 
  val2
}

struct Struct1 { 
  field1: MyEnum1,
  field2: String
}

fn fn1(a: Struct1, b: String, c: String) {
  let let1 = fn2(&a.field1);
}


fn fn2(a: &MyEnum1) {
  let a11 = *a; // error
  let s = Struct1 { field1: a11, field2: "fdsfds".to_string() };
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
```

The error is  error: **cannot move out of borrowed content**

I was suggested by the compiler to use `ref` or `ref mut`, I tried to use them and still that didn't help.

```
fn fn2(a: &MyEnum1) {
  let ref a11 = *a; // still the error
  let s = Struct1 { field1: *a11, field2: "fdsfds".to_string() };
}
```

Comment: actually the error is now in the next line, not in the line you added the `still the error` comment

Comment: the solution is to implement copy, the question is about "cannot move out of borrowed content", I think this is very much a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

The function `fn2` receives a *reference* to a `MyEnum1` as a parameter, but the `Struct1` contains an *owned* `MyEnum1`. This means that you are actually trying to turn a reference into an owned value, which is only possible if you copy the data.

## Long answer

Your code would work if `MyEnum1` implemented the `Copy` trait (which in turn requires implementing the `Clone` trait). If a type implements `Copy`, it will be automatically copied when you dereference it and when you assign it (for example, the `i32` type in the standard library implements `Copy`). Try something like the following:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum MyEnum1 {
  val1, 
  val2
}
```

You may also choose to implement only `Clone` and clone the object explicitly, in case your data structure is expensive to copy (for example, the `String` struct in the standard library implements `Clone` but not `Copy`). Then you would need to use the following code:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum MyEnum1 {
  val1, 
  val2
}

fn fn2(a: &MyEnum1) {
  let s = Struct1 { field1: a.clone(), field2: "fdsfds".to_string() };
}
```

Finally, you may also choose to pass the `MyEnum1` by value, instead of by reference. Then, the only change you need to apply is:

```
fn fn1(a: Struct1, b: String, c: String) {
  let let1 = fn2(a.field1);
}

fn fn2(a: MyEnum1) {
  let s = Struct1 { field1: a, field2: "fdsfds".to_string() };
}
```