# "cannot move out of borrowed content" with operator overloading

Tags: rust

I'm getting a compilation error from a simple helper method, when using a class with operator overloading. Here is a self-contained test (simplified from my real code, but still demonstrating the problem):

```
use std::ops::{Add, Sub, Neg, Mul, Div};

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Money {
    cents: i64,
}
impl Money {
    pub fn new(cents: i64) -> Money {
        Money { cents: cents }
    }
}
impl Add for Money {
    type Output = Money;
    fn add(self, other: Money) -> Money {
        Money { cents: self.cents + other.cents }
    }
}
impl Mul<Money> for f64 {
    type Output = Money;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Money) -> Money {
        Money { cents: (self * rhs.cents as f64) as i64 }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AbsOrPerc {
    pub absolute: Money,
    pub percent: f64,
}
impl AbsOrPerc {
    pub fn new(abs: Money, perc: f64) -> AbsOrPerc {
        AbsOrPerc {
            absolute: abs,
            percent: perc,
        }
    }

    pub fn total(&self, basis: Money) -> Money {
        // This works:
        // Money::new((self.absolute.cents as f64 + self.percent * basis.cents as f64) as i64)
        // This doesn't:
        self.absolute + self.percent * basis
    }
}
```

I'm trying to compile this with Rust 1.8, but I'm getting this error:

```
src/lib.rs:42:5: 42:9 error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
src/lib.rs:42     self.absolute + self.percent * basis
```

I've read the Rust Book, and the parts about ownership and borrowing over and over. I've read numerous questions here on StackOverflow about this question, e.g.:

[Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158738/cannot-move-out-of-borrowed-content)

I don't think my own question is a duplicate because while the error is the same, the circumstances are different. Also if I knew how those other questions applied to this one, I wouldn't have to ask. :-)

So my question is: how can I resolve this error? I don't want to change `&self` to `self`, because that causes other problems.

Besides just fixing the problem, I would also like to know what Rust is scared of. I don't see any dangers here.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28595075/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/29926724/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/30974593/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/28527702/155423, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34621969/155423, and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28843931/155423.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're implementing the operators on `Money` rather than `&Money`. This means that the operator will *take ownership* of its operands. Therefore, in `total`, to perform the addition, you'd have to move `self.absolute`, which isn't allowed because you can't move out of a borrowed pointer (you can only move values you have ownership of). Rust will *copy* values if their type implements [`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) (which is the case for primitives like `i32` or `f64`); otherwise, it will *move* them, which means that the source will be unusable after the move.

If your `Money` struct really only contains a `cents` field, I recommend you make it implement `Copy` (which also requires implementing [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), which would be a good idea to implement even if you don't implement `Copy`). You can implement `Copy` and `Clone` easily with `#[derive]`:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Money {
    cents: i64,
}
```

Now, in `total`, instead of moving `self.absolute`, Rust will copy it instead. If you can't implement `Copy`, then replace `self.absolute` with `self.absolute.clone()`.

---

If you had implemented the operators on `&Money`, then you could just pass references to your `Money` values. For example, with such implementations, `total` could be implemented like this:

```
pub fn total(&self, basis: Money) -> Money {
    &self.absolute + &(self.percent * &basis)
}
```

Comment: It may be worth commenting on ownership and the fact that `Add` consumes the addends by value, maybe even touching on why such a thing is useful and why implementing `Add` on a reference would allow someone to avoid implementing `Copy` if they needed to.

Comment: I think it deserves to recall Rust is _move by default_ (in args just like in assignments), which is generally alien to newcomers, with a reference. Good answer.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Copy/move/borrow is slowly sinking in. This answer helps a lot! Also pedagogically, binaries are easier to understand, and the Book never to my knowledge really presents them as (Copy vs Move) vs Borrow---it always seems to contrast two and not mention the third. Putting all three together is very helpful.